# Not redirecting to the bookmark's url link

Tags: django

In my userpage, when I click on the links that i have bookmarked, its not redirecting into its respective URLs. Please guide me. Thank you.

My views.py:

```
def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404('Reqested user not found.')

    bookmarks = user.bookmark_set.all()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'username':username,
        'bookmarks':bookmarks
        })
    return render_to_response('user_page.html',variables)
```

My user_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} {{username}} {% endblock %}
{% block head %} Bookmarks for {{username}} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if bookmarks %}
        <ul>
            {% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
                <li><a href="{{bookmark.url.link}}">{{bookmark.title}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No bookmarks found.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

class Bookmark(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link) 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return '%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.link.url)
```

Comment: can you show your `Bookmark` models?

Comment: Sure! Thanks by the way.
My Bookmarks models:

Comment: Sorry. Here's my model:

`class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.link.url)`

Comment: Is the `url` field in `link` `None` by any chance ?

Comment: I am sorry, i'm having bad broadband connection in here. Anyways, n i don't think its none. 
Here's my link model:
`Class link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url`
And by the way, when I check in the shell, i get all the url that i saved. Please guide me.
Thank you.

Comment: BSNL Woes? Anyways.. Do a view source once the template `{{bookmark.url.link}}` loads and see if the correct URL is loaded

Comment: Okay, i checked it with the view source, and yes, its (URLs)  not there in the link, just the title. Why is it so?

Comment: Oh. Wait  you dont have A field url in bookmarks  its called link.

Comment: You mean in Bookmark class? I think, because its connected with the class Link, and there it has a url field there. Am sorry if this is not how it works. Please explain.

Comment: It should be `bookmark.link.url`

Comment: Okay!!! That did solved the problem! It should have been `{{bookmark.link.url}}`. Thank you again Karthik!

Comment: I shall mark this as an answer. Just accept it, so it can help in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
{{bookmark.link.url}}
```

as against

```
{{bookmark.url.link}}
```

Since the FK field on `bookmark` is `link` and not `url`